# Will I get a raise in a contract-to-hire position?

Tags: salary, recruitment, negotiation, contractors, consultants

Sorry if this question has been asked and if so please share any links with me.

Currently I am working in a contract to hire position and my manager through the final company has already spoken to me about me staying with the company. He has expressed to me on more than a few occasions that he would like me to be there if I want to stay. I really enjoy the new work that I do and everyone I work with is pretty nice as well.

To get to the point. To be transparent, I am getting a rate of a few dollars short of $50/hr on W2. I know the the recruiting company that I am going through is probably getting close to double that if not more. Is it possible for me to get some of that money when I transition over to the new company since my manager doesn’t know exactly how much I currently make? Should I be speaking with my recruiter/account manager about this or how should I handle this situation? I have a little under 30 days before I start the transition process. Any information is helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you already accept an offer for the employee position?  Do you have an offer in writing from the company for that position?  You get to negotiate this offer.

Comment: Peter - No I have not accepted nor negotiated anything. I actually spoke with the hiring manager today about the position and he said that is still mine if I want it. I am trying to figure out what will possibly happen in the conversion process. Could I possibly lose some of my salary to gain benefits or could I get a raise and still gain benefits? I have spoke with a few friends who say that they got a raise with their company because they were able to get some of the money that the recruiter was getting. Is that normal? I am suppose to meet with my account manager tomorrow.

Comment: Compare benefits.  If the company you're getting paid from doesn't pay when you're on the bench, that's a plus for employee status.  Then decide how much stability and knowing you like what you're doing is worth to you.

Comment: David - The current recruiting agency that I am working for I don’t know much about their bench situation as I only am working with them for this contract to hire position.

Comment: Joe - You are correct my manager could know how much I am getting paid. The reason I said that I don’t think that he does is due to previous knowledge I had about my recruiting company. Also, I asked my recruiter for more money after I had the final interview and she came back a few hours later with $5+/hr increase. The hiring manager was on vacation at the time. So unless she contacted him while he was on vacation I’m assuming that money came from their cut.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, you should inquire with your hiring manager about the salary policy at the place,
Usually, when you transition from the contractor to salary employee, you get a employer`s going rate with some fluctuation, that you can affect by negotiation.
But until you have signed offer, its all fluid.

According to my experience, <50 $/hr on W2 contract is not too much.
Although it depends on your location.

Would be nice to hear the rest of the story as it unfolds.
Thank you

Comment: I will definitely provide an update once it is all figured out. An <50/hr for my location is good. It could be better, but with cost of living as low as it is here it works for me. When I talk to my account manager tomorrow I will see if she knows what the company is looking to pay someone.

Answer (score 1):

Look at it like if you directly applied as an FTE as that is what the conversion process is.  You will go through the boarding process again, but as an FTE filling out benefits, getting a new salary, etc... Thereby just like if you applied for the position directly, the salary is somewhat negotiable and depends on factors such as experience and the position.

It never hurts to ask for the salary you want and wait for feedback, worst they can say is no and you go from there.

Comment: That’s a good point. I hadn’t thought about it in that way. Thanks!